# Address speakers of a 5.1 system directly

Tags: audio, driver

I would like to have a program that is able to address the speakers of a 5.1 system directly. That is, I would like to program a player which plays an audiofile over the exact speaker I want it to, and change respective speaker gradually throughout the file.
That is what I want to do, however I have no clue how to do that. Is that possible with any high-level programming language, or would I need to interact with the soundcard/sound drivers directly [because if so, I would need to give it up right away]... Is that possible, and does anybody know what libraries would help me anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible.  A more specific answer would be possible if you answer a few questions.

1) What OS are you using?
2) How are you speakers connected to the computer?  A digital connection via 1x RCA or TOSLINK connector, or are you using an analog connection via 3x headphone connectors?

If you are using 3x analog connections, then just use [OpenAL Soft](http://openal-soft.org/index.html).

If you are using a digital connection, your audio will need to be encoded into a surround sound compressed format such as AC-3 or DTS.  Of the two AC-3 is probably easier to find an appropriate encoder library for.  You can probably just use ffmpeg (libavcodec), but double check that licensing is compatible with your project.

Ideally, if you are using a digital connection, you would add AC-3 support to OpenAL Soft so that a common API can be used either way and to benefit others.

Also, depending on your OS, there may be a simpler OS specific approach.  For instance, if you are using a digital connection on linux, you can configure an ALSA plugin to do the AC-3 encoding for you, then use the higher level multi-channel API of your choice, such as Jack or PortAudio.

**EDIT**: HDMI is a bit out of my range of experience.  If you treat HDMI like S/PDIF or TOSLINK, it should work fine, but with higher CPU load and possibly compression artifacts.  However, Google searches suggest that under Windows, with the HDMI Audio driver configured correctly (which does seem to cause trouble for some users), you should be able to treat the HDMI audio as a 6 channel audio output.

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to mention those things...
-I am preferably using Windows 10, but Ubuntu would be fine, too...
-Its hooked via HDMI, so digital....

Comment: Also, after looking into ffmpeg real quick, it doesn't seem real-time, does it?
I was hoping for something realtime, that the audiofile doesn't need to be converged, but that I can choose live on which speakers it plays...

Comment: Using ffmpeg for this would mean using the libavcodec that is part of ffmpeg.  libavcodec is capable of realtime compression and decompression, assuming the computer can keep up, which is likely only a problem for compressing high resolution video.